# Why tensor indexing on GPU calls GPU->CPU memcpy and cudaStreamSync?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I found some results on PyTorch that are very interesting and cannot be easily understood.

Here's the code example.

```
import torch
import torch.cuda.nvtx as nvtx_cuda
torch.cuda.cudart().cudaProfilerStart()

idx = torch.tensor([2,3,4], device="cuda")

tensor_0 = torch.rand(6, device="cuda")
tensor_1 = torch.rand(6, device="cuda")

nvtx_cuda.range_push("S0")
for i in idx:
    tensor_0[i] = tensor_0[i] + tensor_1[i]
nvtx_cuda.range_pop()

nvtx_cuda.range_push("S1")
for i in range(4):
    tensor_0[i] = tensor_0[i] + tensor_1[i]
nvtx_cuda.range_pop()

idx = [2,3,4]
nvtx_cuda.range_push("S2")
for i in idx:
    tensor_0[i] = tensor_0[i] + tensor_1[i]
nvtx_cuda.range_pop()


torch.cuda.cudart().cudaProfilerStop()
```

And this is the Nsys output of this code.

[image]

As we can see in this figure, for case "S0", even though all the tensors are already on the GPU, including `idx,` but it calls GPU->CPU memcpy and cudaSteamSync.

However, in the case of "S1" and "S2", it doesn't call GPU->CPU memcpy calls. Rather, it calls DtoD calls. How does that happen?

So here're my question.

- Why does only tensor idx call GPU->CPU memcpy and cudaStreamSync?
- Why "S1" and "S2" doesn't call memcpy? are they (=idx) placed on GPU by any chance?

Comment: The second "S1" is actually "S2" in the figure. Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: All this code runs on the CPU, the GPU isn’t running Python. So how do you imagine a host loop like “S0”  could work without copying the contents of the tensor to the host first?

Comment: @talonmies, You're missing the point. Then why S1 and S2 don't call CPU memcpy and cudaSync? I know the CPU does run Python code since it's host and GPU is a slave device. But the question is why different actions are happening for S0, S1, and S2.

Comment: I am not missing the point, your question is. In S1 and S2  the index (either the range or the list) is in host memory. So no copying is required. In S0 the index is in GPU memory and it’s contents must be transferred to the host before those values can be used within the loop

Comment: Great, I got the point. You're RIGHT. I understand. Would you please write an answer plz? I would like to adopt it.

Comment: So basically, for statement should be executed by the CPU since GPU cannot do that. That's why if the index is in the GPU, then it requires iterative memcpy. I really appreciate it.
Additionally, I just found that `idx.tolist()` can eliminate the iterative memcpy. Then I have one more question: can the list only reside in the CPU?

Comment: Again, **all** the code in your question is run by the CPU. All of it. Within the tensor class is operator implementations which can use backend dispatch logic to run some operations on the GPU. But all that code is normal Python code running on a CPU interpreter is a completely normal way